# Choosing between Zustandspassiv and Vorgangspassiv

Tags: passive

To practise using the two different types of passive voice, I have referred to [a post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20164/the-three-german-passive-past-tenses/20168#20168) in german stack-exchange about the two types of passive as well as [this webpage](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=114) which emphasises when *Zustandspassiv* should be used.  With this in mind, I attempted to translate the following sentence from English.

Last autumn the coat was unfortunately stained by some skin cream.

*1. Im letzten Herbst ist der Mantel leider durch etwas Hautcreme
    befleckt worden. (Vorgangspassiv)*

*2. Im letzten Herbst ist der Mantel leider durch etwas Hautcreme befleckt gewesen. (Zustandspassiv)*

Since I want the emphasis to be on the fact that the coat became stained and not the process, I chose option 2 (*Zustandspassiv*).

However, I got some feedback that number (1) is the correct one.

I would like to know what logic to use when choosing between the two passive options.

Comment: Du lebst doch in Wien, also in einer Umgebung in der man Deutsch spricht. Und deine Fragen in german.stackexchange lassen erkennen, dass sich deine Deutschkenntnisse auf einem hohen Niveau befinden. Möglicherweise bist du sogar Muttersprachler. Warum um alles in der Welt stellst du deine Fragen aber alle in englischer Sprache? Die bisherigen Antworten zu dieser Frage hier stammt von Leuten, die in Stuttgart und Hamburg leben und deren Muttersprache vermutlich auch Deutsch ist. Aber beide halten sich natürlich an die Regel die Antwort in derselben Sprache ... (Fortsetzung im nächsten Kommentar)

Comment: (Fortsetzung) ... wie die Frage zu verfassen. Dadurch entsteht folgende Situation: Ich (Muttersprache Deutsch, lebe wie du in Wien) lese eine Frage die einen besonderen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache betrifft, und die jemand geschrieben hat der gut Deutsch kann, in einem Forum das sich mit deutscher Sprache befasst, und ich lese Antworten dazu die deutschsprachige Deutsche verfasst haben, aber um all das verstehen zu können worüber sich ein Wiener, ein Stuttgarter und ein Hamburger unterhalten muss ich eine Fremdsprache beherrschen. Das ist absurd! Bitte schreibe Deutsch wenn du es eh kannst!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich glaub zu dem Thema gibts einige Meta-Fragen, aber im Wesentlich ist jedem freigestellt, ob er auf Deutsch oder Englisch fragt. Vorteil Englisch: JEDER kann die Frage verstehen, eben auch dann, wenn er/sie nicht das Deutsche so sehr beherrscht. Nachteil: Falls OP des Englischen nicht ganz so mächtig ist, könnnen schon mal Missverständnisse auftreten. Letzten Endes ist es aber OPs Entscheidung.

Comment: @SatishVasan Both sentence are correct. You might hear "war befleckt gewesen" because Past Perfect is often used, too.

Comment: Falsch! Jeder, der german.stackexchange besucht, spricht DEUTSCH. Zumindest gut genug, um Fragen und Antworten in deutscher Sprache lesen und verstehen zu können. Sonst wären diese Leute nicht hier. Aber die Italiener, Russen, Japaner usw. die alle ebenfalls versuchen Deutsch zu lernen, aber keine englischen Muttersprachler sind, zwingt man hier zuerst Englisch zu lernen, damit sie sich hier über die deutsche Sprache informieren können. Das ist das was ich so absurd finde.

Comment: This comment thread has put a smile on my face. I am not a Viennese native, the only thing I have been doing is studiously learning German for the last four months.   I found it hard to convey my question in German, therefore the English.  But it seems as if I have made some progress.  Thank you very much to all for your feedback!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... Ich denke nicht, dass jeder hier genug Deutsch spricht, um Fragen über Deutsch zu verstehen. Hier sind auch A1 Studenten. Zudem ist das Menü in Englisch, genauso wie die Tags. Die Seite ist im Kern also auf Englisch. Und wer kein Englisch kann wird diese Seite kaum finden, da er oder sie nicht auf Englisch suchen wird.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich will ja nicht, dass alle auf Deutsch schreiben. Das wäre auch falsch. Aber ich bezweifle, dass sich Anfänger mit Dingen wie Zustands- und Aktivitätspassiv, dem *zum* im Namen des Gasthofs »Zum goldenen Hirschen«, oder dem Plural »Hosen« wenn nur eine Hose gemeint ist, beschäftigen. Um überhaupt auf die Idee zu kommen solche Fragen zu stellen, muss man bereits gute Kenntnisse der deutschen Sprache haben. Wenn man schon so gut ist, dass man sich für solche Fragen interessiert, wird man aber auch die in Deutsch verfassten Fragen und Antworten lesen und verstehen können.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial point in your examples is that they are in the perfect tense. This tense implies that an occurrence in the past has consequences in the present, and that makes it important how you word things (even with semi-grammaticalised auxiliary verbs).

(1) says that the *act of staining* was last year, and it implies that the coat *is still stained*.

(2) says that the *state of being stained* was last year. Normally such a state continues unchanged, so saying explicitly that it was in the past implies that *it is no longer stained* (maybe you had it cleaned). And mentioning the episode at all implies that there is some other consequence, e.g. "...and ever since then my sister thinks I'm a slob". If that or something similar isn't what you want to convey, then (1) is the better wording.

Comment: Die Zeitform »Perferkt« (in Deutschland: »vollendete Gegenwart«, »Vorgegenwart« oder »2. Vergangenheit«, in Österreich einfach nur »Vergangenheit« genannt) hat in deutschem Deutsch eine andere Bedeutung als in österreichischem Deutsch. Der Fragesteller lebt (wie ich) in Wien, daher wird er sich vermutlich auf österreichisches Deutsch beziehen, und da bedeutet es NICHT zwingend, dass der Fleck noch immer da ist. »Der Mantel ist befleckt worden.« bedeutet in österreichischem (Hoch-)Deutsch nur, dass es passiert ist, nicht jedoch, dass das noch in die Gegenwart nachwirkt (egal auf welche Weise).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Als Hamburger finde ich diese Unterscheidung faszinierend. Kann man darüber mehr nachlesen?

Comment: Ich habe hier etwas ausführlicher darüber berichtet: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-einer-spachvarietät-und-einem-dialekt/11113#11113
Wikipedia liefert in http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Präteritum diesen kurzen Hinweis: »In den Mundarten und der Alltagssprache in der Mitte und im Süden des deutschen Sprachgebiets ist das Präteritum bis auf Reliktformen (war und wollte) verschwunden, während es im Norden Deutschlands – recht stark vom Perfekt abgegrenzt – auch in mündlicher Sprache benutzt wird.«

Comment: Quote: "in the perfect tense. This tense implies that an occurrence in the past has consequences in the present"... this statement is definitely false. Hence -1

Answer (score 3):

You correctly found out about the two different passives are called Vorgangspassiv and Zustandspassiv.

Looking at what those words mean might help. "Vorgang" is process and "Zustand" is a state. You want to point out that the coat *was stained* - *to be stained* is a **process**.

However, when you try to point out that you coat *had a stain last autumn* (having a stain is a **state**) you might use the second one, the Zustandspassiv.

Answer (score 1):

Eigentlich ist Zustandspassiv ein irreführendender Begriff. "Die Tür ist frisch gestrichen" – hier denke ich gar nicht an Passiv, sondern an eine Aussage wie "Die Tür ist neu" – also Verb sein + Adjektiv. Natürlich kann man auch ein Adjektiv in Form des Partizips Perfekt Passiv nehmen wie lackiert, gereinigt, repariert usw.

Ich glaube, mit dem Begriff Zustandspassiv schafft man bloß Schwierigkeiten. Der Begriff Zustandspassiv ist zwar in deutschen Grammatiken üblich, es sollte aber jeder Lernende prüfen, ob der Begriff für ihn hilfreich ist oder eher das Verstehen einer einfachen Struktur wie Kopulaverb sein + Ergänzung verbaut. Man kann bei Beschreibung von Sprache auch "falsche Querverbindungen" schaffen und auf einmal werden Dinge, die eigentlich einfach sind, zu einem Problem.

Eigentlich bezieht sich "Passiv" auf eine Aktion und "Zustand" auf Nicht-Aktion. Somit enthält der Begriff Zustandspassiv zwei Begriffe, die sich gegenseitig ausschließen. Schon das zeigt, wie unglücklich dieser Begriff ist.