# Past participle verb as adjective vs passive sentence?

Tags: difference, passive

I'm confused with these two sentences:

- Im Schaufenster sind Winterschuhe ausgestellt # past participle verb as adjective
- Im Schaufenster werden Winterschuhe ausgestellt # passive sentence

Do these sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Please read about the difference between *Zustandspassiv* and *Vorgangspassiv* in a grammar book.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences have different meanings and highlight the *Zustandpassiv* (focus on state after an action<sup>1</sup>) and *Vorgangspassiv* (focus on an action<sup>1</sup>) forms of the passive.  There is a [previous post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/choosing-between-zustandspassiv-and-vorgangspassiv) that goes into this topic.  To summarise:

> *Im Schaufenster sind Winterschuhe ausgestellt.*

This is the *Zustandpassiv* form of the passive in the present tense.
Focus on state after an action.

Focus on state.. = The winter shoes **are in a state of exhibition** in the display window.
..after an action = After the shop keeper physically setting up the winter shoes as an exhibition.

> *Im Schaufenster werden Winterschuhe ausgestellt.*

This is the *Vorgangspassiv* form of the passive in the present tense.
Focus on an action.

Focus on an action = The winter shoes **are in the act / process of being exhibited** in the display window.  (The shop keeper is setting up the winter shoes for exhibition.)

Here are a few online sources that go into the details of the passive:

1. [The Passive Voice (das Passiv)](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Passive/Passiv.html) - German Studies, Dartmouth College
2. [Aktiv und Passiv im Deutschen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktiv_und_Passiv_im_Deutschen) - de.wikipedia
3. [The Three(?) German Passive Past Tenses](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20164/the-three-german-passive-past-tenses/20168#20168) - German Stack Exchange